# Shell script to determine the file size in a folder recursively

Tags: macos, filesystem, command-line

Can anyone provide me with a shell script that I can run against various folders to see where large files are lurking?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find . -exec du -h {}\;
```

is recursive and displays the size in human readable form.

Or if you're using fish or zsh:

```
du -h ./**/*
```

Comment: Thanks all. +1 to both. I will mark Max's as correct, as I ended up using "du -h > filesizes"

Comment: now I can muck around with the file in Numbers (copy and paste), sort by file size etc..

Comment: bash 4.0 and later also support `**` with `shopt -s globstar`, and in bash you can use just `**` instead of `**/*`.

Comment: What's the best way to order by size `desc`?

Comment: `du | sort -nr`

Answer (score 6):

You can just run

```
du -sm *
```

to see the size of all folders in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Or, as an alternative, you could install the freeware Disk Inventory X. Shows you the largest files on your hard drive or in particular directories with a fun visual interface. And you can move items to the trash right from that interface.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The asker is looking for a shell script solution, I don't think that Disk Inventory X is scriptable.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tree --du -h .`. `--du` calculates the size of the contents of directories (like `du`) and `-h` uses human-readable file sizes.

Or if you only want to see the sizes of the contents of directories, use just `du` or `du -h`. You can use `gsort -h` to sort the output of `du -h`.

You can install `tree` and `gsort` with `brew install tree sortutils`.

Comment: Is `tree` installed by default?